# Using routes from one sinatra app from another when racked up

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra, rack

In the real world, thanks to Rack::Builder, I've started up two sinatra apps and mapped one to "/api/v1" and the other to "/ui".

I'd like the app mapped to /ui to be able to take advantage of the routes in /api but,
becuase they're separate, the ui app can't perform calls on the api side of things.

Is there a way to call one app's route from another via rack, or should I just use Net::HTTP ?

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#/usr/bin/ruby
require 'sinatra'

class API < Sinatra::Base
  get '/accounts/' do
    '{"json":"account_data"}'
  end
end

class UI < Sinatra::Base
  get '/accounts/' do
    # How do I get /api/accounts?
    # call "/api/accounts" obviously does not work

    # would use erb here to render accounts list in human readable form
  end
end

rack = Rack::Builder.new

rack.map "/ui" do
  run UI.new
end

rack.map "/api" do
  run API.new
end

Rack::Server.start :app => rack
exit
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these apps are racked up in Rack together, they have no real connectivity.  What Rack does call `.call(env)` on whatever app you have racked up and that responds with `[status,env,body]`  You can have layers in the middle that act on and modify `env`. Your Rack is triggering `#call` on whatever app you mapped to respond to that path. The called app has no concept of what is running in Rack. Nor can it call another app unless there is a handle for it in `env` that was populated upstream.

But you have to consider why you decided to make these 2 different apps in the first place.  I would imagine it is due to the fact that there could be multiple apps using the API.  Or you enjoy the decoupled nature.  So in that case you have to think if you would want some coupling through Rack at all.  What if the API was on another server?  Any internal link between the 2 through Rack would break the UI application.  If you always know your API will be self contained on the same machine you could just as well make it a library and not do HTTP calls.

So even if it is possible to call routes from a co racked up app I would never do it. The whole reason for having API servers is to have a decoupled layer.  And you should access that layer via HTTP so it would work if it were on same box or across the world.

Comment: Right, decoupling is the goal. I was originally thinkng about getting some test-unit like behavior, but later I decided that I'm more scared of, for lack of a better term, favoritism.  Thank you very much!